# Trying to center side by side divs

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to have 4 divs sit side by side and have them centered on the page but all 4 divs seem to sit slightly left inside of the container.

Looks something like this:

```
{ [Div 1]    [Div 2]    [Div 3]    [Div 4]           }
```

Where the container is centered on the page but the divs inside are not.

Here's my code that's replicated for each div:

```
<div class="container-1">
<div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <--DIVS 2-4 HERE-->
 </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.container-1{
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px;

width: 90%;
text-align: center;
border: 3px solid red;
}


.table-col-1{
padding: 1.5em;
float: left;
width: 20%;   
}

.table-head-1{
padding: 1.5em;
background-color: #515251;
float: left;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.table-text{
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 18px;
padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.text-container{
padding-top: 7em;
padding-bottom: 3em;   
}

.border-1{
border: 2px solid #000000;
} 

.button{
background-color: #d6e042;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 15px;
}
```

All of this has been patched together from the information that I could find on here, but now I'm stuck and can't find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your problem can't be replicated with only code above. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: It would further be helpful if you could make this into a stack snippet, so we can see the result right here.

Comment: You're using float:left; and width: 20%; but only have 4 divs (80% space used), so that space on the right is the missing 20% that would make 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `float: left` to `display: inline-block` and the elements will center.

```css
.container-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.table-col-1 {
  padding: 1.5em;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table-head-1 {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: #515251;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.table-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.text-container {
  padding-top: 7em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.border-1 {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.button {
  background-color: #d6e042;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
<div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Or if you prefer to use flexbox, apply `display: flex; justify-content: center;` to `.container-1` and remove the float from `.table-col-1` - or don't, that part isn't necessary and will be unused if the parent is flex.

```css
.container-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table-col-1 {
  padding: 1.5em;
  width: 20%;
}

.table-head-1 {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background-color: #515251;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.table-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.text-container {
  padding-top: 7em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.border-1 {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.button {
  background-color: #d6e042;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
<div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
    <div class="table-head-1"> 
     <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="text-container">
      <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions/improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">OneDrive/ODB web</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else with this problem I replaced ALL float: lefts; with display: inline-block; and it worked!

Comment: @mp849 no problem. Also updated my answer with the flexbox solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you are trying to get at.

My answer uses flex-box. I know flexboxes sound scary when you have never implemented them yet, but please visit the folowing link to view the code and solution to see how they work. They are amazing.

https://codepen.io/sequential/pen/LxvJrr

Using `display: flex`, `flex-direction: row`, `justify-content: center`, make this formatting task easy to accomplish.

Also this is a good article to read further.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hope this helps and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @mp849 Interesting, well I'm glad you found an answer that did :)

Comment: @Sequential pro-tip - if you're going to make a demo, make one with OP's code. They probably applied the properties to the wrong selector or something.